# Can consular security staff carry firearms in New York City?

Tags: united-states, international, firearms, new-york-city

Can the security staff (equivalent to the [U.S. Diplomatic Security Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_Security_Service)) of the various Embassies/Missions/Consulates/etc located in New York City carry (concealed) firearms as part of their official duties providing security for their diplomatic staff while not on embassy grounds?  Have these rules changed any since the 1960's?

Comment: Are you asking about locally recruited security staff or about foreign staff who enjoy diplomatic immunity?

Comment: Foreign staff - the equivalent of the [US Diplomatic Security Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_Security_Service).

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/27813/36368

Answer (score 3):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In Germany, diplomatic/consular security staff will be issued a *gun ownership card* and a *gun license*, which the Embassy or Consulate will apply for directly at the Foreign Office (State Department) or local authority where the Consulate is based.

This is based on the relevant articles of both Conventions requiring that the laws and regulations of the receiving State be respected.

> **Article 41** (Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations)
> **Article 55** (Vienna Convention on Consular Relations)
> (same text in both conventions)
>
> 1. Without prejudice to their privileges and immunities, it is the duty of all persons enjoying such privileges and immunities **to respect the laws and regulations of the receiving State**. They also have a duty not to interfere in the internal affairs of that State.
>
> ...

The US *Diplomatic and
Consular Immunity: Guidance for Law Enforcement and Judicial Authorities*, from August 2018, (which can be downloaded here: [Information for Law Enforcement - United States Department of State](https://www.state.gov/information-for-law-enforcement)) does not meantion weapons, but the *Local Law Enforcement and Foreign Mission Personnel* does:

> **Firearms**:
>
> - Permission to possess firearms must be obtained from the local state jurisdiction where the owner resides or proposes to carry such a weapon and is valid only consistent with the rules of the issuing jurisdiction.
> - The DOS cannot intervene in the application/ determination process of any firearms application. Also, the DOS cannot intervene if a local jurisdiction denies a firearms permit to foreign mission personnel.
> - The DOS considers the failure to adhere to local firearms regulations to be a serious matter and reminds all persons enjoying immunity that the Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations (VCDR), Article 41, and the Vienna Convention on Consular Relations (VCCR), Article 55, mandate that persons enjoying immunity are to “respect the laws and regulations of the receiving state.”

The *Department of State* (DOS) obviously expects that the local firearms regulations be respected and will not intervene should the local authority deny a firearms permit to foreign mission personnel.

Therefore if they have the required permits, issued by the responsible authorities, they may carry (concealed) firearms as part of their official duties providing security for their diplomatic staff while not on embassy grounds.

---

> [2015-09-15: Zur Behandlung von Diplomaten und anderen bevorrechtigten Personen in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland - Auswärtiges Amt](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/blob/259366/95fb05e9a6a89de129f15d27f92f00aa/rundschreiben-beh-diplomaten-data.pdf)  (PDF)
>
> > **On the treatment of diplomats and other privileged persons in the Federal Republic of Germany - Federal Foreign Office**
> > This circular explains the legal status of diplomats and other privileged persons in Germany.  The explanations are intended to facilitate the implementation of the relevant regulations and to ensure that this group of people is treated appropriately by German authorities and courts.
>
> **Grundlagen der Privilegierung bevorrechtigter Personen und Institutionen**
>
> - (PDF page 8)
>
> Mitglieder diplomatischer Missionen und konsularischer Vertretungen sowie Bedienstete, Vertreter der Mitgliedsstaaten und Sachverständige bei Internationalen Organisationen sowie Mitglieder weiterer bevorrechtigter Personengruppen genießen bei ihrem (dienstlichen) Aufenthalt in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland bestimmte Vorrechte und Befreiungen. Die Grundlagen für diese Privilegien finden sich in den allgemeinen Regeln des Völkerrechts, die nach dem Grundgesetz Bestandteil des Bundesrechtes sind, und in besonderen völkerrechtlichen Vereinbarungen, wie z. B. dem Wiener Übereinkommen über diplomatische Beziehungen [WÜD], dem Wiener Übereinkommen über konsularische Beziehungen oder besonderen bilateralen Vereinbarungen [WÜK]. **Alle Personen, die Vorrechte und Befreiungen genießen, sind unbeschadet dieser Privilegierungen verpflichtet, die in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland geltenden Gesetze und anderen Rechtsvorschriften zu beachten und sich nicht in innere Angelegenheiten der Bundesrepublik Deutschland einzumischen** (so z. B. normiert in Art. 41 Abs. 1 WÜD und Art. 55 Abs. 1 WÜK).
>
> > **Basics of privileged persons and institutions**
> > Members of diplomatic missions and consular representations as well as employees, representatives of the member states and experts at international organizations as well as members of other privileged groups of people enjoy certain privileges and exemptions during their (official) stay in the Federal Republic of Germany.  The basis for these privileges can be found in the general rules of international law, which according to the Basic Law are part of federal law, and in special international agreements, such as the Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations [VCDR], the Vienna Convention on Consular Relations [VCCR] or special bilateral agreements. **Irrespective of these privileges, all persons who enjoy privileges and exemptions are obliged to observe the laws and other legal provisions applicable in the Federal Republic of Germany and not to interfere in the internal affairs of the Federal Republic of Germany** (as stipulated, for example, in Art. 41 Para.  1 VCDR and Art. 55 para. 1 VCCR).
>
> ---
>
> **Waffengesetz  (WaffG) vom 11. Oktober 2002** [Weapons Act]
>
> - (PDF page 40)
>
> Nach § 48 Absatz 2 Nummer 1 i. V. m. § 10 Absatz 1, 4 und 5 WaffG bzw. § 56 WaffG können zum Erwerb und Besitz von Schusswaffen und Munition sowie zum Führen von Schusswaffen an Diplomaten, Konsularbeamte und sonstige gleichgestellte bevorrechtigte ausländische Personen, Staatsgäste sowie Personen, die zum Schutz von Staatsgästen aus anderen Staaten in Deutschland eingesetzt sind, folgende Berechtigungen ausgestellt werden:
>
> > According to § 48 paragraph 2 number 1 i.  In conjunction with § 10 paragraphs 1, 4 and 5 WaffG and § 56 WaffG, diplomats, consular officials and other equal privileged foreign persons, state guests and persons who are required to protect  are used by state guests from other countries in Germany, the following authorizations are issued:
>
> An Mitglieder diplomatischer Missionen und berufskonsularischer Vertretungen wird die Erlaubnis zum Erwerb und Besitz von Schusswaffen und Munition (durch Waffenbesitzkarte) sowie zu deren Führen (durch Waffenschein) gemäß § 10 Absatz 1, 3 und 4 WaffG auf besonderen Antrag durch das Bundesverwaltungsamt, 50728 Köln, erteilt (Diplomaten beantragen die Waffenbesitzkarte und den Waffenschein über das Auswärtige Amt in Berlin, Angehörige der Generalkonsulate legen ihre Anträge über die Senats- oder Staatskanzlei in dem Bundesland, in dem die konsularische Vertretung ihren Sitz hat, vor).
>
> > Members of diplomatic missions and career consular posts are granted permission to purchase and own firearms and ammunition (through a gun ownership card) and to carry them (through a gun license) in accordance with § 10 paragraphs 1, 3 and 4 WaffG upon special application by the Federal Office of Administration, 50728 Cologne,  granted (**diplomats** apply for the gun ownership card and the gun license through the *Federal Foreign Office* in Berlin, members of the **Consulate General** submit their applications through the Senate or State Chancellery in the *federal state in which the consular representation is located*).

Comment: Do note, that the usual background checks for gun ownership in german are **not** done for applications by diplomatic corps and their bodyguard staff - they are rubberstamped.

Comment: @Trish Yes, that can be assumed just as some form of background check will be done before the receiving State agrees to the appointment. (The source doesn't go into detail about this)

Comment: It may be of interest that the conventions governing the immunity of United Nations members' representatives in New York are actually the United Nations Headquarters Agreement and the Convention on the Privileges and Immunities of the United Nations.  Neither of these seems to specify a duty to respect local laws and regulations, though I can suppose we can infer one because they refer to the Vienna Conventions in a few places.

Comment: Note: the [Convention on the Privileges and Immunities of the United Nations](https://www.icj-cij.org/other-texts/convention-on-the-privileges) is from 1946-02-13 and the *Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations* from 1961-04-18 (15 years later).

Answer (score 0):

A license is required, see [NYC Administrative Code §10-301](https://nycadministrativecode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/c09/#chapter-1-public-safety). [This page](https://licensing.nypdonline.org/new-app-instruction/) describes the procedure: the license type is presumably a "carry guard license". You must also get a New York State pistol license. There are various training requirements. [Title 38 of the Rules of the City of New York ch. 5](https://rulesofnyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/c20/#chapter-5-handgun-licenses) (handgun licenses) says what the police department rules are for licensing, §5-04 describes the Carry Guard License, which basically says you must show the need to be armed and that you have any required licenses. If you can do this, they may issue you a license. You cannot carry a concealed firearm off the job just because you are consular security staff.

Comment: Foreign consular staff enjoy official acts immunity.  This should exempt them from state and city jurisdiction when they are on the job.  Missions to the UN and their staff typically have diplomatic immunity, which also exempts them from state and city jurisdiction for private acts.

Comment: @phoog Immunity does not mean license to break the law. There are diplomatic ways to hold immune offenders to account e.g. send them back home.

Comment: @Greendrake A order to expel someone with diplomatic immunity is a political act for which violation of domestic law is neither a requirement, nor something that results in automatic expulsion. It is just one factor among many considered by the State Department is making a decision to do so.

Comment: @Greendrake but the immunity from state law exempts diplomats from needing driver's licenses and from needing to register their vehicles with the state.  Instead, they get licenses from the State Department and register their vehicles with them as well.  If immunity exempts them from one licensing regime, it will exempt them from the other.

Comment: @phoog Good to know re driver licenses. But, there must be a line dividing the laws that diplomats are exempted from and those they must follow like everyone else e.g. the prohibition to steal, commit murder etc. Firearms licenses are not as ubiquitous in NY as driver licenses, and they well could be on the other side of the dividing line.

Comment: @Greendrake the DoS is not going to expel trained security agents who carry firearms responsibly in a manner that would otherwise be lawful but for their lack of a license granted by a government from whose jurisdiction they are immune. Diplomacy is reciprocal: if the DoS expects to be able to provide armed guards for US dignitaries in (e.g.) Israel, it has to allow (e.g.) Israel to provide armed guards in the US. Conversely, if it expects Israel to rely on the Diplomatic Security Service and the NYPD in New York, it must rely on Israeli agencies there.  I don't know which it actually is.

Comment: @phoog - "Some" foreign consular staff enjoy immunity, certainly not all. My (British) wife worked in the British Consulate in NYC and, along with most of her British colleagues, enjoyed no immunity. That was reserved for higher ranking government officials.

Comment: @LaconicDroid "along with most of her British colleagues, enjoyed no immunity": that's highly unlikely.  Consular officers are also immune, but consular immunity, defined in a different convention, covers only official acts.  Diplomatic immunity is much broader.  What visa did your wife have?  (In any event, foreign security officers will be diplomatic agents, not consular.)

Comment: @ohwilleke the decision to expel may be informed by political considerations.  But the actual action is a legal one.  It changes the legal status of the subject of the action.

Comment: @grovkin expulsion does not change the legal status of a diplomat; the person remains a diplomat enjoying diplomatic immunity.  The only way for a diplomat to lose diplomatic immunity is for the sending state to waive the immunity or to dismiss the diplomat from his or her diplomatic position (and even then the diplomat retains immunity to allow him or her to depart).

Comment: @LaconicDroid that has nothing to do with her being or having been British; consular immunity is not personal as is diplomatic immunity. The latter is constant until waived such immunities by the sending State. Consular staff, generally, only enjoy inviolability relating to the consular post.

Comment: @kisspuska it was related to her being British in that she would have been treated differently had she been a US citizen or permanent resident.

Comment: @phoog Do you have a reference for diplomatic exemption from drivers license/vehicle registration?  (I'm not doubting the statement.)

Comment: @user11421 is https://www.state.gov/key-topics-diplomatic-motor-vehicle-program/ what you had in mind?

Comment: @phoog D'oh! Exactly what I was looking for.  Now I'm wondering if the Contact Us link at state.gov would answer my original question...

Comment: @phoog Article 41/55 also requires them **to respect the laws and regulations of the receiving State**. Both, taken togeather, must be taken into consideration. Cherrypicking the one and ignoring the other will only lead to a incorrect conclusion.

Comment: Your links (as of 2022-08-18) are all broken (Sorry. This page does not exist yet.)

Comment: @MarkJohnson I'm well aware of the duty to respect laws and regulations.  One practical consequence of that is the Department of State's diplomatic motor vehicle program.  As your answer (which I have upvoted) shows, the state department has approached firearms differently, in effect using its power to expel diplomats as an enforcement mechanism to require compliance with state and local laws and regulations, since the state and local enforcement mechanisms (i.e. state courts) have no power of enforcement. As an example of diplomats routinely shirking their duty, consider parking tickets.

Answer (score 0):

[Diplomatic and Consular Immunity: Guidance for Law Enforcement and Judicial Authorities](https://web.archive.org/web/20220110053454/https://www.state.gov/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/2018-DipConImm_v5_Web.pdf) explains the extent to which persons with diplomatic immunity are not subjects to the laws of the US:

> Personal Inviolability
> vs. Public Safety
> Personal inviolability is enjoyed to some
> degree by a majority of foreign diplomatic
> and consular personnel. **This inviolability
> generally precludes handcuffing, arrest,
> or detention in any form and forbids U.S.
> authorities from entering the residences,
> automobiles, or other property of protected
> persons. Personal inviolability is, however,
> qualified by the understanding, well
> established in international practice, that
> the host country does not give up its right to
> protect the safety and welfare of its populace
> and retains the right, in extraordinary
> circumstances, to prevent the commission
> of a crime.**
> Thus, in circumstances where public safety
> is in imminent danger or it is apparent that
> a grave crime may otherwise be committed,
> police authorities may intervene to the
> extent necessary to halt such activity. This
> naturally includes the power of the police
> to defend themselves from personal harm.

So law enforcement can stop a shooting in progress, but they cannot arrest a person with immunity if they arrive at the scene of the shooting after the crime has taken place.  If a person with immunity carries a holstered gun and presents credentials demonstrating immunity, they cannot be questioned any further unless they acquiesce to the questioning.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  If a person with diplomatic immunity carries a weapon without the agreement (or at least acquiescence) of the US Department of State, that person risks being expelled from the US.  So, while it is true that there are no criminal consequences for such a person violating US criminal law (including NY state and city laws), that's not the same as those people being permitted to do so.

Comment: In other words, the NYPD is powerless to prevent diplomatic or consular staff from wielding weapons in the performance of their duties, as is every other agency of New York City and New York State along with most of the federal government.  But the State Department is _not_ powerless to prevent it, so the question of whether it is permitted is essentially a question of State Department policy.

Comment: @phoog you are interpreting the question too broadly. It asks specifically about NYC. This obviously implies that it is about the authority of NYS LE. If you want to split hairs and pretend that it is a question about any LE in NY, go ahead. But I am gonna interpret the question in what I view to be most reasonable way to interpret it.  Although even your characterization of  State Department actions as LE actions is obviously inaccurate.

Comment: The US Department of State has the authority to impose different requirements on consular and diplomatic staff in different cities because of local laws.  The fact that local laws are of interest to the asker of the question does not imply that the question concerns only the powers of local law enforcement.  I don't think this question is about law enforcement at all.  It's about diplomatic immunity.  Consider the question "can diplomats shoot schoolchildren in New York City?" -- the answer is 'no, they'll be expelled of they do," even though the NYPD can't arrest them.

Comment: @phoog It implies exactly what you say it doesn't imply.  And, in addition, you are wrong because the State Department does not impose requirements (that would be a unilateral action).  The requirements result from international treaties and protocols.

Comment: The international treaties in this case are known as the Vienna Conventions. 
Have you read them?  They provide that the State Department can expel foreign diplomatic and consular staff _for any reason or for none at all._  Whether a foreign consular guard can carry a firearm is entirely at the discretion of the Secretary of State.  The exercise of this discretion may be influenced by reciprocity or negotiations with the foreign staff member's sending state, but, regardless, that discretion is the only thing that is relevant to this question.

Comment: @phoog you seem to have veered off the topic.  good day.

Comment: @phoog no, they don't. The only discretion they have is to tell the mission to pack up its toys. Any other action is a violation of international law. Now, the U.S. Supreme Court proudly declared the I.C.J. having no jurisdiction in U.S. soil, but of course both the administration and the legislative branch loves to go and cry to mommy when they don't like something in the world that it take action. Except if the little f— brat does something blatantly disgusting either at home our outside of its jurisdiction. Just because they can, doesn't mean they may as a matter of law.

Comment: Any law contrary to the "supreme [l]aw of the [l]and" including those "self-executing" treaties protected by the U.S. constitution make any subordinate law null and void to at least the extent they conflict. The State Department can, they — for example under a reasonable administration like the current one recognizing international law as an important asset to its own prosperity — wouldn't.

Comment: @kisspuska in addition to having the capacity to tell the mission to leave, they have the capacity to tell any single member of the mission's diplomatic and consular staff to leave.  And they can therefore place conditions on the conduct of those staff members.  For example, they [regulate how they drive](https://www.state.gov/about-us-diplomatic-motor-vehicle-program/) ("monitors driving records to ensure unsafe drivers are removed from the road").  If they wanted to have a similar program for firearms, they could.  I don't know whether they do.

Comment: @grovkin The question was specific to NYC because of the large number of diplomats in the area due to the United Nations and the stricter gun control laws there.  Having given this more thought, I would *assume* that the rules I am asking about would be uniform across the country.

Comment: @user11421, grovkin: it has occurred to me that the international treaties governing the immunity of members of missions to the United Nations are not in fact the Vienna Conventions but the _Convention on the Privileges and Immunities of the United Nations_ and the UN Headquarters Agreement.  The details of the provisions are basically the same, but if it ever came down to a dispute about the interpretation of the international agreement, these documents would be the starting point.

Answer (score -3):

**Vienna Convention on Consular Relations, April 24, 1963 21 U.S.T. 77 596 U.N.T.S. 261 Article 31:**

"A diplomatic agent shall enjoy immunity from the criminal jurisdiction of the receiving State."<sup>1</sup><sup>2</sup><sup>3</sup>

End of story.

---

[1](https://legal.un.org/ilc/texts/instruments/english/conventions/9_1_1961.pdf) "He shall also enjoy immunity from its civil and administrative jurisdiction, except in [cases irrelevant herein]”

2 It became the "supreme [l]aw of the [l]and" under Article IV, section 2, of the U.S. Constitution after congress ratified it in 1973 without further action required on the part of any States.

[3](https://treaties.un.org/pages/ViewDetails.aspx?src=TREATY&mtdsg_no=III-3&chapter=3) No objections raised relating to the immunities provided by Article 31 by any of the high party signors, assentors, or ratifiers.

Comment: Having immunity is by no means the end of the story. 
 Consular staff will be expelled from the US if they commit crimes.  The question asks whether they are permitted to carry firearms, not whether they are subject to criminal penalties for carrying firearms.  If they are not permitted to carry them, this will be enforced by expulsion from the country, not through the criminal courts.

Comment: Your quoted text doesn't even *appear* in the VCCR. -1.

Comment: Article 55 (VCCR) also exists: that requires them **to respect the laws and regulations of the receiving State**. So it is **not** the end of the story. Article 41 (*Consular officers shall not be liable to arrest or detention pending trial, except in the case of a grave crime and pursuant to a decision by the competent judicial authority*) is only a **part** of the story. Both must be taken togeather. [end of story]

Comment: @cpast but it does appear in the Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations, where it is indeed the first paragraph of article 31.  But staff of missions to the UN are actually governed by UN documents, not the Vienna Convention.  There are general provisions in the Convention on the Privileges and Immunities of the United Nations and specific provisions in the United Nations Headquarters Agreement.